# RDFa output and Panels

Tags: 7, panels, rdf

I need to get RDFa working with Panels.  As it currently stands, fields output with panels or panelizer will have their `property` fields set correctly.  You can see an example of this at http://schema.org/Product when you look at the bottom and view RDFa output.

The part that isn't working is getting all of the properties to be wrapped by their proper type, in this case [Drug](http://schema.org/Drug).  So at some point, all of the output fields need to be contained within a wrapper that has the attribute `typeof="Product"`.

Panels has no support for this, but you can see an example of what it would look like if you looked at some sample node output.  The node container wrapper would look something like this.

```
<div id="node-121" class="node node--product node--full node--product--full clearfix" about="/products/sample-product" typeof="schema:Product sioc:Item foaf:Document" role="article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
```

That's your typical RDFa output when rendering output with `node.tpl.php`.  Panels doesn't use this though, so it never gets rendered.

I'm hoping someone out there has dealt with this situation.  Structured data is pretty common to see these days, and so is the use of Drupal with Panels.  Someone has to have tackled this problem before, and I'm just looking for the best solution possible at this time.  Thanks.

**TL;DR:** What is the best way to get RDFa working with Panels?  Specifically, getting the `typeof` property added to some wrapper element which contains all of the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, and something I'm hoping to tackle at some point in the next couple of months: https://drupal.org/node/1485074 (see in particular comments #5 and #8). Feel free to subscribe to that issue as well.

Comment: I did end up browsing through that thread, forgot to follow though.  Thanks Scor.